# mount_smbfs inconsistent behavior mac osx

Tags: bash, macos

I can use "mount_smbfs //$uname:$passwd@$ip/$share mountpoint/"
This command works by itself, or when run in a plain bash script.

I have a bash script in which I call a python script (using selenium) to configure a server. Once the python script completes, I try to mount the newly created smb share and write to it. I keep getting this error: "mount_smbfs: server connection failed: invalid arguement". Exit code is 68.

Again, this command works fine when used everywhere else, except in this script. I can see the syntax is exactly the same when the command runs.

I know that this is not a problem with my server, I mount through AFP before SMB, so I know it's not a timing issue.

Is there some problem I'm unaware of when mixing languages in a script? Any insight is appreciated.

Edit:
I am not sure why, but I just added a loop condition and to retry after failure and it works fine on the second try.

Comment: Since the command only fails for you inside the script, don't you suppose that we might need some of the details of the script to answer the question?  But don't give us the whole script.  Figure out what you can cut out of it while retaining the failure behavior.  Cut it down as much as possible, and present *that*, along with any inputs needed to reproduce the problem.  This is what we call a [mcve].

Comment: My guess would be it's something to do with how the various strings are getting parsed as they're passed from python to the shell script to the `mount_smbfs` program. But as @JohnBollinger said, it's hard to tell without the relevant details.

Comment: I apologize for the vague-ness. This is just a script that calls two independent scripts. The only relation is that the first script uses a browser tool to configure the server that the 2nd script is accessing.  I've updated the original post; I was able to just add a loop condition to retry the mount if it fails. This appears to have fixed the problem and will mount on the 2nd attempt. I was unable to reproduce the problem using Mac client as SMB server.